# css file not applying style component in

Tags: reactjs

this is my css file Header.css

```
.header{
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
}
```

My Header.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'



const Header = () => {
return (
<div className = "header">
<p> hope u enjoyed it here</p>
</div>
);
}



export default Header;
```

these are The imports in the App.js file

```
import Recipe from './Recipe';
import Header from './layout/Header';
import Footer from './layout/Footer';
import Nav from './layout/Nav';
```

I've tried making a Nav Component but for some reason thats not rendering either.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Guess that your question is wrong. A CSS File can’t be rendered literally, just Apply style to some components, so, is CSS File style not applied to header or the header File is not shown in app?

Comment: im so sorry, the header is showing but not the style

Comment: Your code is essentially fine. The only possible cause I can think of is that `./Header.css` is not actually located relative to `Header.js` so the import path is incorrect.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-murdock-6n04v?file=/src/App.js:135-140). Might be a good idea to create a sanbox that reproduces the problem, so the problem is easier to diagnose.